# How to access mySQL from Node.js Terminal

Tags: mysql, node.js, terminal

I'm quite new to node but believe I have the correct setup here.

I am working locally and have done... npm install mysql -g

When I go to type mysql -p in the node terminal it says that mysql is unrecognized. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: npm install mysql -g won't necessarily install mysql on your machine, unless i'm mistaken.  so commands are usually just executable applications that are found under a particular path, in Linux (& mac) it'll be an environment variable named $PATH and in windoze %PATH% - in whatever terminal you have, it probably doesn't include the mysql directory in the PATH environment variable - i recommend that you google how the PATH environment variable works at a minimum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mysql` module on npm does not provide any command-line tools, so installing it globally is of no use.

To use the `mysql` module, you will have to write your own script according to [the module's documentation](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/master/Readme.md).

Comment: Ah I see. I am just getting into the backend. 

I am able to use the plain mysql terminal but don't know how to integrate that with node. I know node-mysql is one such integration albeit without terminal support. Is there a module that allows mysql to be accessed from the node terminal or is node-mysql the best and I just have to write all the scripts. Just beginning I would like being able to use the terminal you know.